# Loading two layouts with two RecyclerViews

Tags: android, android-intent, android-recyclerview

I want to be given a clue of loading **two** `RecyclerViews`. Below is my description;

1.I have an  App which first launches the list of items in the `RecyclerView`.

2.What  i want when i  choose any one item of the first `RecyclerView` to load another Recyclerview in the next activity automatically.

**NOTE:**

Suppose am retrieving data from the server (e.g using JSON) , and it goes into the first RecyclerView , then afterwards i choose any item in it to load another RecyclerView in the next `Activity` with the same data(e.g JSON data).

**Without creating intents to load each of the items in the First `RecyclerView`, but just using a SingleItemView class to load a next Activity with a `Recyclerview`**

**Meaning a `recyclerView` to load another `Recyclerview` ?**

Does anyone have any site or clue for such an example. because i have searched ,but am getting no answer.
please help ..

Comment: I have no code ,  but i want a clue like any example site, because am a beginner i may end up posting the whole project here which is bad @Jared

Comment: you can use the same adapter or store the data in a common location and feed it to the adapters.

Comment: thanks @Umang Chamaria , does my scenario have a common name ?

Comment: did not get you. what do you mean by having common name? I am talking about storing in common location like shared preference or database or even a static class if that works for you.

Comment: Yeah,  shared preference